# Is it possible to mark all articles in a group as "unread" in Feedly?

Tags: rss, rss-reader, feedly

I have added several interesting blogs to my feedly RSS feed, but I would like to mark all the articles there as unread. Is there a way to do that in feedly?

Answer (score 9):

You can now on a item-by-item basis. The quickest way is using the keyboard shortcuts `n` to select the next article in the current feed and then `m` to toogle read status to *unread*.

Comment: That's at least something, thanks, however some RSSs are hundreds of articles long. Upvote, but no answer yet

Answer (score 1):

Scroll down to load all articles inside the feed you want to mark as unread,
press F12 to open the Developer Tools Console, paste the following code in the console, and hit enter ([source](https://feedly.uservoice.com/forums/192636-suggestions/suggestions/30956584-mark-all-unread)):

```
document 
 .querySelectorAll('.mark-as-read') 
 .forEach(markAsReadButton => { 
   if (markAsReadButton.title === 'Mark as unread') { 
     markAsReadButton.click() 
   } 
 })
```

It works, but you have to remember that Feedly, at least on the free program, only saves articles 30 days old, so only these will be saved as unread.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://feedly.com/i/label/feedly.history and log in. open console and write in:

`document.querySelectorAll('.EntryMarkAsReadButton.rounded.EntryToolbar__button.button-icon-only').forEach(div => {div.click()})`

this works for have loaded and read news, so you shoul reload website and run this command in console again until all news will be marked as unread.

Answer (score 0):

Building on HeyJude's answer, slightly less tedious than scrolling with the mouse-view.

Open the [Developer Tools Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools).

Spam these lines a few times to scroll to the bottom of the page and trigger more articles to be loaded on the page:

```
headings = document.querySelectorAll('.EntryList__heading'); 
headings[headings.length-1].scrollIntoView();
```

Then, once you've loaded a month's worth of articles:

```
document.
  querySelectorAll('.EntryMarkAsReadButton').
  forEach(buttonElement => {
    buttonElement.click()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Still couldn't find this feature today. A workaround I recently found is as follow (I tested it on Chrome browser)

1. Click the 'check' button, then select "Older than one day"
2. Immediately click "undo" on the bottom right corner.

by now, all the articles older than one day are marked as unread. You'll have to mark today's articles as unread one by one, though.